# More than one row insertion occuring while using android and wamp server in a single button click

Tags: php, android, wampserver

I am using WampServer for doing a webservice application in android. But On a single button click in application the same field inserting 4 times in phpmyadmin table.I set ID  as primary key.so the id will be different for each entry.

Here is my android Code

```
 package com.example.androidhive;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

 import java.util.List;

 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
 import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;

public class NewProductActivity extends Activity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputName;
EditText inputPrice;
EditText inputDesc;

// url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "http://192.168.1.11/android_connect/create_product.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

    // Edit Text
    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
    inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
    inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

    // Create button
    Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

    // button click event
    btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    JSONObject json;
    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
        String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag


        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done


        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            /*if (success == 1) {*/
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            /*} else {
                // failed to create product
            }*/
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}}
```

Here is My Php Code

```
 <?php

 $response = array();
 if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {

 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $price = $_POST['price'];
 $description = $_POST['description'];

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql inserting a new row
 $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(name, price, description) VALUES('$name', '$price',      '$description')");

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit();
 } else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
 }
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);}
?
```

Comment: sorry, i have checked your code, nothing wrong for me , but , why you put the 'exit();' in the php file under the if statment ??

Comment: without exit also there is same error

Comment: okay, i suggest you to check the 'AllProductsActivity', because after clicking on your button ( the onPostExecute()) you start this activity, so i suggest you to check what you had coded under this activity ...

Comment: Actually i also checked that.In AllProductsActivity there is a code for getting datas from the server.

Comment: Problem is nor with that.Because I checked app by removing that intent which directs to AllProductivity class. Then also the same field is inserting four times

Comment: The PHP Code should only create one new row. So check the Apache Access log to see if your App is sending more than one request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require_once **DIR** . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();`

It is working now.It is the problem with PHP file. I removed the above code from the PHP file and given the code for connection directly.Now it is working fine.